# ASP.NET Call webMethod via Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I've been working on a project for school and I within that project I want to call a server method (C# method) via the client side. I found out that using jQuery is one of the better methods to do this (because of ajax). And I got it working but after a week or more it suddenly stopped working. I don't think I changed much to the method, except the name. But I can't seem to figure out the problem. (I used debugging to check whether the method gets called or not and it doesn't seem to be calling).

The code I have for calling the WebMethod via Ajax:

```
function callDatabase() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Index.aspx/setGridData',
        data: '{ }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

I found that piece of code here on Stackoverflow.

Then I use this as my method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void setGridData() {
        string data = "Test";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null) {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE userdata SET griddata = ? WHERE userid = ?;");
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("griddata", data));
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userid", HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString()));
            MySqlDataReader reader = Global.SqlConnection.executeSQLCommand(command);

            if (reader.RecordsAffected <= 0) {
                reader.Close();
                command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO userdata(userid, griddata) VALUES (?, ?);");
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userid", HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("griddata", data));
                reader = Global.SqlConnection.executeSQLCommand(command);

                reader.Close();
            } else {
                reader.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

The jQuery is in a folder called "JavaScript" and the WebMethod is outside the folder, if this helps.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: does it enter in the back end method? ..and also if you use session on back end don't you need to put [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]

Comment: also check the path of the back end page... (think from the root of the server)

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi It doesn't enter the back-end method no. I just tried using the `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` version still doesn't work.

Comment: can you see any error in browser console? also check the response code for ajax call. Is it 404 or something else. check this in network tab of browser's developer console.

Comment: check the path of back end uri ..and maybe try somehting like:   url: './Index.aspx/setGridData',

Comment: @vijayP I checked the browser console. It doesn't return any error.

Comment: what **does** it return? In addition to `success` handler, `$.ajax` has `error` handler - use it.

Comment: can you define "not working" for us please? If you set a breakpoint in the webmethod does it get hit? Does the webmethod fail with an exception of any kind? If not, look in your browser network tab and see if the ajax call is responding with some HTTP error code (i.e. not a 200 OK). Also look again at the jQuery ajax docs (api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and implement the "error" callback - this will report errors that you can log to the console.

Comment: your `setGridData` does not return anything, yet the expected `dataType` is `"json"` - what's up with that?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your comment. It doesn't hit a breakpoint. Will try the error report in ajax. The network tab says error code: 200

Comment: 200 means OK, not error. That's the standard HTTP code for a successful request. Assuming you looked at the right call. Does your `alert(msg)` run when the call returns?

Comment: @ADyson I've put the error alert message. I got the error "Undefined"

Comment: Two things I notice which _might_ have an effect. 1 - the webmethod has no parameters, but you send it an empty object, not sure if it will like this or not. Try changing `data: '{ }'` to `data: null`, or even removing that line entirely. 2 - your ajax call is expecting "msg" back as a parameter, but the webmethod is void, so no return type. Try changing it to return a simple `string`, it can just say "Completed successfully" or something, but it would make the two bits of code consistent.

Comment: if you got "undefined", you perhaps didn't alert it properly. Try this version of the callback: `error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                alert("An error occurred : " + jQXHR.status + " " + errorThrown);`
                    }

Comment: @ADyson now the message is: `[object Object]`

Comment: @ADyson When I added your error alert message and now it calls the back-end method.

Comment: adding my error method wouldn't have caused it to suddenly start reaching the backend, it merely improves the reporting _afterwards_. You must have changed something else too? Try to change one thing at a time and check the effect.

Comment: @ADyson Alright I think I figured it out. what I do is this: I call the method `callDatabase();` and that should do the ajax. But after I have called the database I refresh the webpage and somehow that messes up the back-end part. `var newUrl = updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "Selected", "none");
        window.location = newUrl;`

Comment: well it would interrupt the connection between client and server. Possibly depending how you've written it, the refresh could even happen before the ajax is initiated. ajax is asynchronous - if you want your refresh to happen after the database call finishes, then you must put the refresh code in the "success" method. Otherwise it will get executed in parallel.

Comment: Although if you are refreshing immediately afterwards, I wonder why you need ajax at all - why not just do a normal postback of the form? That will give you one less call to the network, and a lot less javascript.

Comment: @ADyson I've put the refresh code in the succes function, unfortunatly after doing that the back-end won't be called. edit: Nevermind that forgot to remove the old part.

Comment: so does it work now as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting to Database, you want to make sure WebMethod is working.

Here is the working example - client sends *user* object and server returns it back.

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebApplication.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button type="button" onclick="postData();">Post Data</button>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postData() {
                var user = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/postjson") %>',
                    data: "{user:" + JSON.stringify(user) + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebApplication
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string PostJson(User user)
        {
            user.FirstName += "Test";
            user.LastName += "Test";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```