# Calling method from an <li> element , inside the Literal.text string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having the following problem: I want to call a method whenever a specific `li` is clicked. Problem is that the `li` is dynamically created in a `literal.text` string, where I do import things from my database.
Whenever I try to call a method it does not work. I want to call a method whenever the user clicks on each `li` and get that `li` information inside my method (haven't wrote the method code yet, because I can't get it called.)
Thoughts?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="
       + Server.MapPath("~/ebookstoredb.mdb");

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM CATEGORY";

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            String msg = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lit1.Text += "<ul>" + "<li runat=\"server\" OnClick=\"ProductsInfo\">" + reader["ID"]
                    + "," + reader["Name"]
                    + "</li>"
                    + "</ul>";
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void ProductsInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [`BulletedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead of a literal?

Comment: @DStanley It's an exersise for my university class. I am asked to do it with a literal!

Comment: {sigh} you gotta love schools that teach people to do things the wrong way...  So did they teach you how to add a click handler?

Comment: @DStanley I would have answer if they did!

Comment: Two things: 1. move your <ul> and </ul> out of the loop. You're making a list for each item. 2. Have you learned about 'onServerClick'?

Comment: @Tyanna I will have it a look now i guess.

Comment: can you show us the html for this page?

Comment: @AgapwIesu https://gyazo.com/6e256334672367df9d7c71d02f95bb67

Comment: @DimitrisHD ***I don't think your instructor meant to use literal like you described.*** The problem is ***li*** tags are added ***dynamically***, so client-side html cannot call `ProductsInfo()` event unless you make ProductsInfo as [WebMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41508295/296861). It'll add complexity to the code.

Comment: @DimitrisHD Sorry, I gave you the wrong approach.  What I was doing was pretty much duplicating your problem...

Comment: Can you post the _actual_ requirements?  _Forcing_ you to use `Literal` to add client-side HTML that includes a server-side postback is a very odd requirement.

Comment: @DStanley Sure: Create a page that displays all the product categories at the left of our page.The categories menu should be dynamicly created.When you click on each category, you will get all the products in that category.NOTE: Create the category menu with LITERAL.In the text property of LITERAL ,you must create an UL, same in the products case (HTML Table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so guys i found out what was the problem. Our mr.genious instructor told us today that we can use a datagrid..Sigh.
Thanks everyone for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used literals before, but from reading about them... with a literal displaying just static html, you will need to have each li call a javascript function that will then do a postback to the method you want.  So build your `li` like this:

```
 lit1.Text += "<ul><li><a onclick=\"CallProductInfo(" + reader["ID"]+ ")\">" + reader["ID"]
                    + "," + reader["Name"]
              + "</a></li></ul>";
```

Then you have to have a javascript function that does the actual postback to your server side code or redirects to the products info page with the passed id.  That is, in your page (not the code behind), have a script something like this for the postback...

```
<script>
    function CallProductInfo(id)
    {
        __doPostBack('ProductInfoId', id);
    }
</script>
```

In you code behind, in your page load event handler, you'd have something like this:

```
if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "ProductInfoId")
        {
            ProductInfo(Convert.ToInt64(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]));
        }
```

Comment: Can you complete this please?

Comment: Do you really need to post back to a method in your code behind, or just redirect to some page that is going to bring up the info for that particular product id?

Comment: I want to display all the items of each category, so yeah i need a method that does kinda the same thing with the the code above, but for products.(displays all products from the category which is clicked)

Comment: I think something like what I have put above will work.  The key is that since the Literal displays static html only (though I have never used literals), you have to call a javascript client side function.  Then the javascript has to do the postback, if you really want to stay on the same page.  The code behind has to distinguish, on postback that you are calling back with a product id, and go to the right method.  Since it is not a proper postback to an event handler, you have to do the EVENTTARGET and EVENTARGUMENT thing.

Comment: While this _technically_ may work I highly doubt that the intent of the assignment was to re-create client-side postback code.

Comment: @DStanley Since he is required to use a literal, to display the list, and then have it clickable to get at the detail, that may be exactly what the instructor is getting at.  I would not be surprised at a professor requiring the use of a literal to force the students into discovering __doPostBack.

Comment: Dimitris - one more thing, you may have to use an anchor tag to make each list item clickable.  I have modified the code that way.  But since I don't want to test this out, it's left to you to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot create server-side events on a Literal Control.

However, you can add client-side javascript functionality to post back a request.

In your aspx using:

```
<div>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Your aspx.cs should contain:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                lit1.Text += "<ul>" + "<li \' onclick=\'javascript: __doPostBack(\"getProduct\", \"1\");\'>"
                             + "Product " + "1"
                             + "</li>"
                             + "</ul>";
            }
            if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "getProduct")
            {
                getProduct_Click(null, null);
            }
        }

        private void getProduct_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("You Clicked on " + Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
        }
```

This will set up each `li` to pass their own value to the event argument hidden control and perform a postback to the server.

You can then check if the event target is the required one and call a method with the value that was posted back.

Just change the sample lit1 text above to iterate through your data.

Comment: It's still not clickable. It's crazy.(function wont be called.)

Comment: Ummm, yes it is. What issue are you having? Do you have the aspx to show what you have? Have you escaped the quotes correctly? Do you get an error in the console of the browser?

Comment: I just did copy and paste your code, the function still wont work :(

Comment: This answer is basically the same thing I have in my answer, just written a little differently.  But it is missing that you may have to put an anchor in the list item to make it clickable.

Comment: Just took a look at the page source of the link you provided - not an aspx, no asp.net controls at all... Try in your own asp.net web app.

Comment: @Agapwlesu, yep - we're just about the same with the answers. The anchor tag will give you the pointer cursor but it will work without. CSS style on the UL or LI will do the same too.